# Windows 8 disable network locations from search

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-search, desktop-search

Using webdrive to mount external SSH/SFTP points, whenever I do a search using File Explorer / Search on Computer, explorer starts to scan these drives as well. Since I have a full ubuntu server mounted as a drive, this results in the whole server's content being downloaded, for a single search.

This is clearly suboptimal.

Tried already:

- Right click / properties on the webdrive does not offer the usual "Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed"
- Search index does not lists the webdrives, and windows in fact does not indexes these locations -it's only file explorer, which rampages through the server
- Even disconnecting the webdrive results in re-mounting it automatically.

In what ways can I not have File Explorer not touch any network locations, ever?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disable search on network drive when doing full computer search

I don't have answer to that. So far I don't see such option.

### Disable indexing

In theory, indexing enable search to return result faster. Disable indexing on those drive *potentially* make the search on them slower. However, not sure how effective indexing is on network drive.

### Search without touching network drive

1. Workaround - Search Specific Drive

   It is possible to do that and not complicated.

   1. Open File Explorer
   2. On left panel, expend `Computer`, select any drive below it (DO NOT select in the right panel)
   3. Enter search term in search box and start searching
   4. File Explorer will only perform search on the selected drive

   For example, if `C:` drive is selected, then only `C:` drive will be searched.

   If there are more than one local drive and you want to search all of them, it become multi-step process.
2. Workaround - Library Folder

   1. Open File Explorer
   2. On left panel, right click on `Libraries`, select `New`, select `Library`
   3. Rename the `New Library` to `Local Drives` (or anything you like)
   4. Right click on library `Local Drives`, select `Properties`
   5. In Prperties windows, click `Add...` and add all local drives into the library

   Whenever you need to search all local drives, select `Local Drives` under `Libraries` on the left panel (again, NOT the right panel), enter search item. It will search only drives added in `Local Drives`.

Comment: Having 9 volumes spanning 3 physical drives mounted under different labels makes this an undesirable option -esp since the intent of my search was universal access to local files.

Comment: That is a lot of drive ... letters!!

Comment: Added a 2nd workaround, should be much more convenient for everyday use.

Comment: I guess that works, upvoted. Will give a day or two to see if there are any other takers, will award bounty otherwise.

Comment: sure no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

An indirect answer : Don't use the Windows search, as there are much better free products
around which are not as broken as that of Windows.

Here are a couple :

[Everything search engine](http://www.voidtools.com/)
Ultra-quick selective search on NTFS volumes. Can select the volumes to index.
May start with Windows and place an icon on the taskbar.

[FileLocator Lite](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=filelocatorlite&page=home)
Non-indexed search by many possible criteria.